# Subset dataframe in a list by a dataframe column criteria

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes. I need to subset a dataframe of this list according to a criteria in one column of the dataframe.

(all dataframes of the list have the same number and names of columns, and the same number of rows)

For example, I have:

```
l <- list(data.frame(x=c(2,3,4,5), y = c(4,4,4,4), z=c(2,3,4,5)),
data.frame(x=c(1,4,7,3), y = c(7,7,7,7), z=c(2,5,7,8)), 
data.frame(x=c(2,3,1,8), y = c(1,1,1,1), z=c(6,4,1,3)))

names(l) <- c("MH1", "MH2","MH3")
```

output

```
$MH1
  x y z
1 2 4 2
2 3 4 3
3 4 4 4
4 5 4 5

$MH2
 x y z
1 1 7 2
2 4 7 5
3 7 7 7
4 3 7 8

$MH3
  x y z
1 2 1 6
2 3 1 4
3 1 1 1
4 8 1 3
```

So I want to subset the dataframe for which column "y" is the closest to a given number. For example if I say a=3, the chosen dataframe should be "MH1" (where column y=4)

If "l" was a dataframe I will do something like:

```
closestDF <- subset(l, abs(l$y - a) == min(abs(l$y - a))
```

How can I do this with the list of dataframes?

Comment: how about `l[[which.min(sapply(l, function(df) sum(abs(df$y - a))))]]`

Comment: Are the values in column `y` identical within a data frame?

Comment: You could also skip the loops and just bind all of them into one data set (because they all have same dimensions) and find the min value, for example using the data table package `rbindlist(l)[, .SD[abs(y - a) == which.min(abs(y - a))]]`

Comment: Or using `dplyr` `bind_rows(l) %>% filter(abs(y-a)==which.min(abs(y-a)))`

Comment: `rbindlist(l)[abs(y - a) == which.min(abs(y - a))]` would be even simpler.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please post your answer

Comment: @shadow Thanks, this option works as I want.

Comment: I also tried @David Arenburg option but it returns me an "empty  data.table (0 rows) of 22 cols:..."

Comment: and for @akrun option maybe i'm missing something because it doesn't find function "%>%", which I even I don't understand what it means... sorry, I'm new in R

Comment: @user3016709 It is the `pipe` or chain operator in dplyr.  It connects the LHS and RHS together.  You have to load `library(dplyr)`

Comment: `rbindlist(l)[abs(y - a) == min(abs(y - a))]` works perfectly fine. Did you install `data.table` package using `install.packages("data.table")` and then `library(data.table)`? akrun is using `dplyr` you also need to install and `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Ok, yes, your option @David Arenburg works correctly! For the other option with library(dplyr) I'm encountering version problems with another package. I'll take a look.

Comment: I have `dplyr_0.4.0`.  `bind_rows` was introduced recently which replaces the `rbind_list`

Comment: Do you know which of your three options will be more computationally faster? In my real code I have a list of several dataframes (more than 50) with several columns inside, and I have to do this operation several times within an iterative process...

Comment: @user3016709 David Arenburg's method should be faster, followed by `dplyr` (not tested though)

Comment: `data.table` and `dplyr` would be far faster than `sapply` loops

Comment: Your question is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195976/subset-a-dataframes-in-a-list-based-on-the-content-of-a-vector/) on that matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the answers and comments of @David Arenburg, @akrun and @shadow, here there are three possible solutions to the problem I posted:

Option 1)

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(l)[abs(y - a) == min(abs(y - a))]
```

Option 2) (needs an R version > 3.1.2)

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(l) %>% filter(abs(y-a)==which.min(abs(y-a)))
```

Option 3) (also works perfectly, but computationally less faster than the first 2 options if used within a big loop or an iterative process)

```
l[[which.min(sapply(l, function(df) sum(abs(df$y - a))))]]
```